# docker run -e not working, bug?

Tags: docker

according to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables):

> Additionally, the operator can set any environment variable in the
>   container by using one or more -e flags, even overriding those
>   mentioned above, or already defined by the developer with a Dockerfile
>   ENV. If the operator names an environment variable without specifying
>   a value, then the current value of the named variable is propagated
>   into the container’s environment:

```
$ export today=Wednesday
$ docker run -e "deep=purple" -e today --rm alpine env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=d2219b854598
deep=purple
today=Wednesday
HOME=/root
```

I tried to run docker run -e with my container:

```
docker run -d -it myimage123 -e "myvar=blah"
```

I get this error:

```
[FATAL tini (7)] exec -e failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Shouldn't your flag go before `myimage123`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

`docker run -d -it -e "myvar=blah" myimage123`

The problem here is that `-e` is a flag and `myimage123` is an argument. So the arguments should always come after the flags.