# docker-compose run -e KEY=VALUE not working using nodejs and protractor

Tags: node.js, protractor, docker-compose

Similar to [docker run -e not working, bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699483/docker-run-e-not-working-bug); except my docker command has its file in the correct order and I'd like to do it all in the command-line:

**CLI**

```
docker-compose up -d selenium
docker-compose port selenium 5900
docker-compose port selenium 4444
docker-compose build desktop
docker-compose run -e TAGS=test desktop
WARNING: The TAGS variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Starting MYTESTSUTIE ... done
```

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
desktop:
  build: .
  command: echo ${TAGS}
```

- Docker-compose v1.16.1
- Node.js v8.7

I have also tried with quotes, with brackets and attempting to escape characters, but nothing works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Before anybody suggests, I did find a way to do this by setting TAGS in advance using *export TAGS="XX"*; but I'd rather not still be reliant on a second command line if I don't have to be.

**EDIT 2:** I have tried updating to 1.18 and am running the script from either a Git Bash terminal or a Docker Quickstart Terminal as I am using a Windows 7 machine as a base-machine; but still no luck.

Comment: i am on docker-compose 1.18 and it is working OK, you should update your system first

Comment: @MazelTov - I just tried using 1.18 and it didn't work. Is there any other suggestions you might have?

Comment: there might be problem if you are in `sh`, i tested that with `bash`...or what is your entrypoint?

Comment: @MazelTov - I am either using Docker Quickstart Terminal or Git Bash (Note: I am using a Windows Machine, so I don't have shell or native Terminal CLI support)

Comment: i am asking what is the entrypoint for that image you are using :-)

Comment: @MazelTov - 
`docker-compose up -d selenium,
docker-compose port selenium 5900,
docker-compose port selenium 4444,
docker-compose build desktop`

This what you were looking for?

Comment: no, i dont know what you are doing with these commands, but if you try `docker-compose run -e TAGS=test selenium bash` it will attach you to the new container and here you can try `echo ${TAGS}`  and here it prints the "test"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166828/discussion-between-raisus-and-mazel-tov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after some communication with @MazelTov, it appears I  can't do that. Unbeknown to me, even though I am already in a docker container to begin with, the command:

```
docker run -e
```

actually creates a new sub-container that gets the -e flag passed to it. This means that the YAML file that I want to pick up the variable can't do so as it's sitting in the host container.

Guess I'll have to use an export command to have it do what I want it to.